# Set hostname on EC2 using cloud-init and instance tags?

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

Is there a way to use the values from instance tags to set the hostname on an EC2 instance, using cloud-init in user-data?

Something like this?

```
#cloud-config
preserve_hostname: false
hostname: my-custom-hostname
fqdn: my-custom-hostname.local
manage_etc_hosts: true
```

Except using an instance tag, such a "Name" or "hostname".  I've seen some examples using Jinja templates, which seems to be along the right lines. But I'm not sure if/how to reference the instance tags in the user-data/cloud-init. If this makes more sense to bake into the AMI, I don't mind that - it doesn't have to be user-data. However, I currently am running a `hostmod.sh` shell script at instance launch that reads the tags, and sets the hostname.

```
## template: jinja
preserve_hostname: false
hostname: {% tags.hostname %}
fqdn: {% tags.hostname %}.local
manage_etc_hosts: true
```

Comment: I can see in the `/var/log/cloud-init.log` that the EC2 instance metadata is being read.  I feel like I'm either close, or approaching this completely the wrong way?

`cloud-init[2412]: url_helper.py[DEBUG]: [0/6] open 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname' with {'url': 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Cloud-Init/0.7.6'}, 'allow_redirects': True, 'method': 'GET', 'timeout': 5.0} configuration`

Answer (score 0):

One idea that worked for me was use shell parameter expansion (I think that's the right term). I am still maintaining my own script, baked into my AMI, but I prefer the template-like approach versus my previous script that used sed to modify the `/etc/hosts` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get Name tag from AWS instance metadata
ec2id=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
hostname=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$ec2id" "Name=key,Values=Name" --region us-east-1 | awk '/"Value":/ {print $2}' | tr -d '",')
fqdn="${hostname}.local"

# Write a new hosts file using variable expansion
cat >/etc/hosts <<EOF
# The following lines are desirable for IPv4 capable hosts
127.0.0.1 ${fqdn} ${hostname}
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ${fqdn} ${hostname}
::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
EOF
```

I run the script via cloud-init defined in user data:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
  - bash /usr/local/bin/hostmod.sh
```

I also tried creating the entire script within user data via cloud-config. This works as well, but I split the file out to make it easier to manage separately in Ansible.

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /usr/local/bin/hostmod.sh
    permissions: 0744
    owner: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash

      ec2id=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
      hostname=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$ec2id" "Name=key,Values=Name" --region us-east-1 | awk '/"Value":/ {print $2}' | tr -d '",')
      fqdn="${hostname}.local"

      cat >/etc/hosts <<EOF
      # The following lines are desirable for IPv4 capable hosts
      127.0.0.1 ${fqdn} ${hostname}
      127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
      127.0.0.1 localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4
      # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
      ::1 ${fqdn} ${hostname}
      ::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
      ::1 localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
      EOF

runcmd:
  - bash /usr/local/bin/hostmod.sh
```

This obviously doesn't change the hostname, which is a bit more platform dependent. That is why I preferred to use cloud-init from the start. I may later add a similar template for updating the hostname.

Comment: You asked "how to set hostname" and provide a round-about answer that doesn't accomplish that. -1

Answer (score 0):

This script will allow you to update the Amazon Linux (v1) hostname configured in `/etc/sysconfig/network` - both parts are necessary to correctly configure the hostname.

```
#! /bin/bash
#
export EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone` 
export EC2_REGION="`echo \"$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE\" | sed 's/[a-z]$//'`"
export ec2id=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id )
export ec2name=$(aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$ec2id" "Name=key,Values=Name" --region $EC2_REGION | awk '/"Value":/ {print $2}' | tr -d '",')
#
hostname ${ec2name}
cat > /etc/sysconfig/network << EOF
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=${ec2name}
NOZEROCONF=yes
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from a few years back and there's a reasonable solution listed, but tags are now available (since jan'22) in the metadata as well (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/instance-tags-amazon-ec2-instance-metadata-service/)
i.e. curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/Name

Cheers
//A

Answer (score 0):

To expand @mack answer, a simple working script to read a tag `hostname` is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
export TAG_HOSTNAME=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/tags/instance/hostname)
hostnamectl set-hostname "$TAG_HOSTNAME"
```

Note that you have to turn on making the instance metadata tags available to the EC2 instance, either via console:

[image: right click instance to enable instance tags]

Or with Terraform, like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "somevm" {
  ...
  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint          = "enabled"
    instance_metadata_tags = "enabled"
  }
}
```