# Passing user-data to EMR EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

EC2 has a well documented way, in StackOverflow and on AWS, to providing UserData:

- [Set hostname on EC2 using cloud-init and instance tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902553/set-hostname-on-ec2-using-cloud-init-and-instance-tags)
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

This allows developers to launch a script early in the machine's boot-up.

However when launching an EMR cluster there doesn't appear to be support for passing along this kind of information. The next best thing would be creating one's own AMI but it would of-course be preferable to avoid that.

My goal is to manually set the hostname of the EMR EC2 machines.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Bootstrap Actions`. You can find out how to set them up at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html

Comment: Thanks I'm familiar with this. However doesn't it run AFTER networking is instantiated? As I mentioned I need to set the "hostname".

Comment: I don't think it's a best practice to set hostnames specially if you are going to take advantage of auto-scaling.

Comment: I know but I have my reasons for wanting to do it. Specifically I need to change the domain from ".ec2.internal" to a custom "mydomain" but without the ability to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html which would do this for me.